# Next dev with yarn doesn't work on freshly created app

Tags: node.js, next.js, yarnpkg, package.json

I created a new app with nextJS.
When I try to launch dev server with `yarn dev` with Webstorm, this appears:

```bash
$ yarn dev
yarn run v1.22.18
$ next dev

Done in 21.44s
```

This issue is specific to this project - other projects with **the exact same dependencies and versions** are running just fine.

Here are all the deps:

```
{
  "name": "project",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/cache": "^11.9.3",
    "@emotion/react": "^11.9.0",
    "@emotion/server": "^11.4.0",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.8.1",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.8.0",
    "@mui/material": "^5.8.0",
    "next": "^13.2.1",
    "next-seo": "^5.4.0",
    "next-sitemap": "^3.1.11",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "8.16.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "^13.2.1"
  }
}
```

I'm still running on node v16.14.1.